# I have 2 price values and I want to calculate the difference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 price range. Regular Price and Offer Price displayed on screen with the below HTML rendered.

I am trying to calculate the price difference using Javascript/jquery and insert a div with the discount price.

```
<div class="price-box">
    <p class="old-price">
        <span class="price-label">Regular Price:</span>
        <span class="price" id="old-price-221">Rs17.00 </span>
    </p>
    <p class="special-price">
        <span class="price-label">Special Price</span>
        <span class="price" id="product-price-221">Rs14.45 </span>
    </p>
    <div>
        <span>Discount Price:</span>
        <span>XXXXXX</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this currency symbol also displayed along with the price. So, I am wondering how to calculate the difference between "Regular Price" and "Special Price".

Can some one please help me?

P.S. I searched the site and did not find the relevant answers.

Comment: will the currency always be _Rs_?

Comment: Work out your logic (price x - price y), work out how to get a value from the element, then do your maths logic. It's pretty easy, try something first and then ask for help. We won't write the code for you ;)

Comment: May be parseFloat is what you are looking for http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Comment: Yes, the currency will always be Rs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There it is : http://jsfiddle.net/s7w98ngt/2/

jQuery part :

```
$('.price-box').each(function(){
var element = $(this),
    oldPriceRaw = element.find('.old-price .price').text(),
    specialPriceRaw = element.find('.special-price .price').text(),
    oldPrice = parseFloat(oldPriceRaw.replace('Rs','')),
    specialPrice = parseFloat(specialPriceRaw.replace('Rs','')),
    diff = 'Rs'+(oldPrice - specialPrice).toFixed(2), // 2 numbers after the comma
    diffElement = element.find('.diff-price');
    diffElement.text(diff);


});
```

HTML a bit modified :

```
<div class="price-box">
<p class="old-price">
<span class="price-label">Regular Price:</span>
<span class="price" id="old-price-221">Rs17.00 </span>
</p>
<p class="special-price">
<span class="price-label">Special Price</span>
<span class="price" id="product-price-221">Rs14.45 </span>
</p>
    <div>
      <span>Discount Price:</span>
      <span class="diff-price"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The tricky thing was to get the current prices value as float numbers. Then, we just calcul the difference.